# Euler-Lagrange equation in vector form

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, notation

If we have a Lagrangian which is a function of vectors $r$ and $r'$ where $r$ is the position with an $x$, $y$ and $z$ component and $r'$ is the time derivative of $r$ are we able to express the euler-lagrange equation as follows:
$$
\nabla_{r} \mathcal{L}-\frac{d}{dt}(\nabla_{r'} \mathcal{L})=0,
$$
where
$$\nabla_{r}=\left[\begin{array}{c} \dfrac{\partial }{\partial x}\\ \dfrac{\partial }{\partial y}\\\dfrac{\partial }{\partial z}\\ \end{array}\right].$$
I think this is equivalent to the euler-lagrange equation below, but I haven't seen it used anywhere, so dunno if im missing something stupid.
$$
\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial r_{i}}-\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial r'_{i}}=0
$$
for $i$ belonging to $(x,y,z)$.

Answer (score 2):

These expressions are not just equivalent.

They are one and the same !

The very definition of $\nabla_r A $ is the vector of components ${\frac {\partial A} {\partial r_i}}$

Comment: having tested a few examples i realised they're only equivalent in the case where the lagrangian only has scalar components, if the lagrangian includes a vector potential it doesn't work, will resolve this tomorrow after some sleep

Comment: @Adrien I really don't understand what you call $\nabla_r$ if you get different results !!!

Comment: if the lagrangian contains a vector e.g V, then each element of the vector V_i will have to be evaluated individually be partially differentiating in x,y and z (and x',y',z'). If you use $$\nabla$$ A_i will only be differentiated with respect to one of them. (not sure if this makes any sense)

Comment: Indeed, what you say does not make sense. That $V_j$ itself has several components has absolutely no effect to make $\nabla_r V_j$ anything else but the vector $\frac{\partial V_j}{\partial r_{i}}$, $V_j$ being any chosen component of  your vector potential. Then the contribution of all  three $V_j$ It is one and the same thing, whatever you apply it to. Don't confuse the index $i$ of the derivation and the index $j$ of the object $A_j$. Then the contribution of all  three $V_j$ must be taken into consideration.

Comment: yes for sure, it works if you apply the gradient to the individual vector components, previously i was imagining you could take the dot product $$\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{V}$$ however in practice it doesnt work

Comment: Just as if you have a charged massive particle in a gravitational potential and also an electrostatic one you have to add the effects of both.

Comment: The Lagrangian is a function, so applying the nabla operator yields a vector.

Answer (score 1):

You can write it, but in the "space of generalized coordinates", i.e. the *configuration space*, since Lagrange equation involves generalized coordinates and not (only) coordinates describing the physical space.

The difference can be subtle, but remember that in general generalized coordinates are not a full set of coordinates describing position in the physical space.

Remember where Lagrange equations come from, i.e. stationary-action principle, that involves variation of the action $S$,

$S = \displaystyle \int_{t_0}^{t_1} L(\dot{q}_k, q_k, t) \, dt $

and thus partial derivatives $\partial L /\partial q_k$,  $\partial L /\partial \dot{q}_k$, without the gradient of any physical quantity in the physical space.

If you really need a gradient, you can think at the generalized coordinates as the orthogonal coordinates of the *configuration space* (the space of generalized coordinates and their time derivatives), s.t. the gradient in this space becomes

$\nabla_{\mathbf{q}} \, f(q_k, \dot{q}_k,t) = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial q_k} \mathbf{\hat{q}}_k + \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \dot{q}_k} \mathbf{\hat{\dot{q}}}_k$,

but this is not the gradient you need/want.

Answer (score 0):

The component form of Euler-Lagrange equation works for any cooordinate of any coordinate system while the vector form of Euler-Lagrange equation works only in Cartesian coordinate system.

The vector form should be interpreted as a shorthand for the three components of Euler-Lagrange equations coorresponding to three coordinates. If you interprete $\nabla_r$ as the gradient operator, for example, in the cylindrical coordinate system, you can not recover the component form of Euler-Lagrange equation.